# Set required true Webix

Tags: webix-jet

`Webix-jet` есть динамическая форма есть две кнопки , форме есть элементы текcта 
когда нажимаю кнопка1 `required: true` должен быть а когда кнопка2 `required: false`

пробывал таким вот образом

```
$$('mainForm').elements['fname'].required = false;
```

и так пробывал

```
$$('mainForm').elements['fname'].attr('required', true)
```

но не работает, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

required - это свойство, а не метод, соответственно, менять его нужно через define, после чего делать refresh. Также у required нет значения false.

Не знаю на сколько правилен мой пример, но можно сделать, например, так:
http://webix.com/snippet/d952a67f